# Python bulk copy tool

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a 3D Artist. I am very new to Python and I am now developing a tool.
I have so many files in my folder, and subfolder more than 1000. I have to copy particular file based on name (not file type) according to my .txt. This text file have name list of which file i am going to copy.

Here I have a script for .txt file reading code:

```
import os
file = open("D:/Python/Test.txt", "r")
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Here i have script for copy files:

```
import shutil
import os
dir1='D:/py_src_souce/'
dir2='E:/py_src_dst/'
for files in os.listdir(dir1):
    shutil.copy2(dir1 +files , dir2+files)
```

Both files are working fine individually, but I don't know how to run script combine above the two codes.
  I want to copy which file name I gave in .txt file, that file only copy to destination folder. Thanks for reading. If anyone can help  me out of this problem, that would be a life-saver for me.

Comment: First learn to write [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and group them in proper [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) - those two concepts are the most basic "code reuse" features (scripts are mostly intended as a way to call functions from modules).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you want to copy all the files listed in Test.txt from dir1 to dir2.

If that's the case you can do :

```
import os
import shutil
with open("D:/Python/Test.txt", "r") as fp:
    files = fp.readlines()
    dir1='D:/py_src_souce/'
    dir2='E:/py_src_dst/'
    for file in files:
        file = file.replace('\n','')
        file1 = os.path.join(dir1,file)
        file2 = os.path.join(dir2,file)
        shutil.copy2(file1,file2)
```

If you want to get fancy you can check to make sure the file exists in dir1 before trying to copy it with os.path.exists(file1) , and make sure it doesnt already exists in dir2.

edit - I added a line to take out the newline chars in Test.txt.  In the error message that you pasted you can see a `\n` (the newline character) at the end of the filename, and that `\n` isn't part of the filename - its there to keep lines separate in the text file.

Comment: Hi jermy_rutman thanks for your answer. I run ur script but its not work, i got some error, here i pasted what getting error whilw Run script....            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/test/venv/read.py", line 10, in <module>

Comment: shutil.copy2(file1,file2) 
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:/py_src_souce/fox\n'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding that you want to run a script from another script? If so, I use `runpy`:

```py
import runpy
runpy.run_path(path_name="otherfile.py")
```

Otherwise, see @jeremy_rutman's post. It was a good one.

Comment: Hi The Tech Robo , thanks for reply. in my ,txt file have, name list of which file i am going to copy.